# Is there any quick way to classify a group from list of abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm trying to solve the following problem

> Classify group of order $720$ which has exactly $14$ elements of order $6$

By using fundamental theorem of abelian groups, I found following $10$ abelian groups of order $720$.

1. $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.
2. $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_9$.
3. $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.
4. $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_9$.
5. $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.
6. $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_9$.
7. $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4 \times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.
8. $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4 \times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_9$.
9. $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2 \times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.
10. $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2 \times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_9$.

How to classify the one asked in question? What is the smartest way to do this? Do we have to count the number of elements in each group individually?

Comment: Sylow-subgroups are a standard approach.

Comment: @dbx : I don't see how Sylows helps here.

Comment: An easier statistic of an abelian group than "how many elements of order exactly $d$" is "how many elements of order dividing $d$", that is, "how many elements $g$ satisfy $g^d=e$". This latter question should be reasonably easy to answer if you know your abelian groups in any concrete form (for example, invariant factor decomposition or primary decomposition); if you answer the latter question for $d=1,2,3,6$, one can then use inclusion-exclusion to answer the former question for $d=6$.

Comment: Please don't use images. They are not searchable, they are not accessible, and they don't adapt to the user's display.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I apologise, will keep that in mind. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since each of your direct factors has prime power order, an element has order dividing $6$ if and only if its coordinates have order $1$, $2$, or $3$. It will have order exactly $6$ if at least one coordinate has order $2$, and at least one has order $3$. Equivalently, the projections onto the $2$-part and the $3$-part must be elements of order $2$ and $3$, respectively; the projection onto the $5$-part is of course trivial. So the number of elements of order $6$ is the product of the number of elements of order $2$ in the $2$-part, and the number of elements of order $3$ in the $3$-part.

So if your $3$-part is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_9$, you have exactly two choices for that part (the two elements of order $3$), whereas if your $3$-part is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ you have $8$ possibilities for that part (every element except the identity).

Similarly with the $2$-part: $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ gives exactly one element of order $2$;  for $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ you have three; for $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8$ you likewise have three; for $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ you have seven; and for $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ you have  fifteen.

Clearly we can discard those final two groups in your list: too many elements of order $6$. If the $3$-part is $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ then the number of elements of order $3$ is $8$, so the number of elements of order $6$ is a multiple of $8$, and so cannot be $14$.

So the $3$-part must be cyclic, and there have to be exactly seven elements of order $2$ in the $2$-part. That means three direct factors in the $2$-part.

Comment: Which group are you getting exactly?

Comment: @MathLover: The only group in your list of ten in which there are exactly three factors of order a power of two and exactly one factor of order a power of $3$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4 \times\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_9$?

Comment: @MathLover: Exactly.